# for loop to create thumbnail pictures on the fly, creating only one image

Tags: php, for-loop, thumbnails

Good day everyone:

I have the task to create thumbnail pictures inside of a directory which contains several hundred pictures, which are regularly modified, deleted or added. My guess is that creating the image of each image in the directory on the fly would be the way. I wrote this test piece of code, which creates the thumbnail and displays it on the screen, but although I have setup a for loop to go through each image inside the directory, it only creates 1 image. I might be having a brain fart and I cannot seem to see where the issue is, can I ask for your expert and fresh set of eyes?

```
    $album = $_GET["album"];
    $dir = "../albums/".$album;
    $imgArray = scandir($dir);
    $l = sizeof($imgArray);
        for($i = 2; $i < $l; $i++){
            $file = "../albums/".$album."/".$imgArray[$i];
            $imageSize = getimagesize($file);
            $owidth = $imageSize[0];
            $oheight = $imageSize[1];
            $nwidth = $owidth/18;
            $nheight = $oheight/18;
            $img = imagecreatefromJPEG($file);
            $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($nwidth,$nheight);
            imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0,0,0,0, $nwidth,$nheight, $owidth, $oheight);
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($tmp_img,null,50);
            imagedestroy($tmp_img);
    };
```

Comment: you dont even write an image to a file? it's unclear what you want to do and what's going wrong...

Comment: The idea is not to save the file and just call it on the fly... It works with the first image of the directory, but the for loop does not continue to create the rest of the images... Since the content changes several times a day, creating images and saving them sounds almost pointless. Does that make sense?

Comment: so you are outputting it to the client? I dont think you can output multiple images

Comment: Yes... The intention is to create a thumbnail for each image in the directory through the for loop without having to save the actual image... If displaying multiple images is not possible, I guess having to evaluate the content every time a call is made to this directory and create the thumbnails of the images that are new and removing the non-existent ones, even evaluating last modified date for the current ones that have only been modified might have to be the way to go.  Suggestions?